# Detect browser close in JSF

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, browser, jsf-2

Is there a way in JSF to detect when a browser/tab is closed?   With ICEfaces one could accomplish this using @WindowDisposed together with the @PreDestroy annotations.  However, not all JSF frameworks have such capability.  The best I have come across so far is using "onbeforeunload" (or an equivalent) in JavaScript.  This, however, isn't browser agnostic, and in particular, I notice that it behaves differently on IE (there is a popup message that asks users to confirm whether it is ok to navigate away or not, and per Microsoft documentation, this message can’t be changed or done away with).

Comment: To really detect a browser close there must be some client-side 'thing'. Otherwise the server can never know when the browser is closed. So I doubt the pure serverside annotation solution of icefaces you describe is really what your title states.

Comment: See http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/ViewScoped. Only with .js you can do it immediately so it is effectivly a client-side initiated solution . Without there will be some delay. But the Omnifaces solution is the waybto go IMO